# ponylang: call constructor method in another constructor?

Tags: ponylang

ENV: ponylang 0.9.0

From [ponylang tutorial](https://tutorial.ponylang.org/types/classes.html)

```
class Wombat
  let name: String
  var _hunger_level: U64

  new create(name': String) =>
    name = name'
    _hunger_level = 0

  new hungry(name': String, hunger': U64) =>
    name = name'
    _hunger_level = hunger'
```

tried following, compiler complains: `constructor with undefined fields`

```
  new create(name': String) =>
    hungry(name', 0)
```

Where to get an exact explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor call in Pony will always create a new object, there are no delegating constructors.

```
new create(name': String) =>
  hungry(name', 0)
```

In your example, the call to `hungry` isn't applied to the object being initialised in `create`, but to the new `Wombat` allocated.

In Pony pseudo-code, this is what's really happening.

```
new create(this: Wombat, name': String) =>
  let new_wombat = Wombat_Alloc()
  hungry(new_wombat, name', 0)
```

Comment: How does the pseudo-code of the correct `create` constructor look like? Does `this` count as alias? What is the exact type of `this`? Given that "A constructor always returns an ephemeral type, because it's a new object."

Comment: Inside of a constructor, `this` is always seen as `Type ref`. Any reference is an alias, and `this` is the only alias of the object at the beginning of a constructor. This is safe even if the constructor returns a unique type (i.e. `new iso create()` or `new trn create()`) because such constructors must have sendable parameters, which means the `ref` alias of `this` won't "leak outside" of the constructor: you can't store it in a `val` or `tag` parameter and if you store it in an `iso` parameter it won't be visible outside of the object because of the isolation boundary of `iso`.